# Styling of paths in hierarchical edge bundling

Tags: ms-access, field, facet, vega

I am trying to visualize edge bundles with different `strokeWidth` but I am not able to get access to the appropriate field in the line mark.

I am using the hierarchical edge bundling example and fed it a dependencies JSON with **weight** field but I am not sure how to access it. I can view the weight in the data viewer of the vega editor as can be seen in the screenshot below. My main conceptual difficulty is in accessing the weight from the facet directive. If I use `groupby` instead of `field` in the facet, I can't figure out how to access either **weight** or **treepath** for the line mark.

I just figured out how to share an example on vega editor. Here is the [link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQQAE4uJgDubRQGttsmkjKKkCbWwBm2sQ8NJFcc3Bxxx88VA0ClLaBnQw2nCyZAra1mwMPrLaxJbaMEE2irA0UEgANpHRnkwMfvk04mSU0iA4SLIWVWgCMmGy9GgA7ABMAAwy8DRkWN39MkgMmGwQNABecGgg4hKLMrNk4gUQaADaoFsIi+iYvrMStcQFDMcAjDJMlbJooJU4U0s2VWsgCJVoA1+SAAHmh7iAIKccADKH1bgBfeFSA62Y4gGwWBg7GRXfI3NA9ABsgMefheIDeH3QXxitT+GnGQNBqAALH0+ojkctUUs4MDTuJMJdrscAMzEh5PcmUoXUpDfOn-VCA5DM8WAyHeMGclFHT5sTBIU7CvF3AAcJKlqFe4nesvR8tpMnpAOdILQ6vWUO1SN1aNO-IAyvMfrj8agzZKydaKbaqQ6Fc6lT03czGZroagEb7uXqTnzMAB5BwOCD6E3hlMgUnPGMyz6On4u5WpsEa71ZnW5tH5JAATwSQpxIqWUDxmsUtRr0rj9ox7FqbFU6h2qF2IDUsj7tTHWNOk4Aul3DmioGx8sYAJKSYempYOYwKTDWOC+EA5k+j8-GQsfW-hkAHw8SEXzfD8eXQYxhkqAANWpElkI00XaehtAIbQenfLlP0g5RaHEABNeCcEQ410CGEZMDQjCsL9JYkCgNRSArY5xAYfJ8hkC411AOBSEFVcNwLVAEASMs2FIScZAQpCllIhgEFYZ4cz43xMEE0SsTgCS4EUXYAEJVMFVhTgQA9iNItE2I498jwPGRSJQHjuyWTAPFDEVV32Cla3BHDqxsf4cxoWsq38-I4FcWp6g8QVtS5EKPRkfy8NGGQYrU+LXlrFlkogkAoF0uAmDgDiFOi9xMtQKtZgWD0AE5RTNYLa1aFz0EKjwSrKhAKti2VRXWEMPTNW4ehatBCTyvMQAi1wAFpOuK0q8QQebIUUBgoD6qrcohYbUEJLpbhZCbUC6aa0VSzBFqK7rVvWtytp2uLUDa2rji6FlRTOyN2vRYYsFurqVoUx7NqgTD0sq173oOr6foS2t6suz5AZupb7rBjattFF7ZThurzu+s7bkBcLIoxu7QbWnHIfxtA9o+ybjtOpGwT8-K5qpkGevB3GGdZIaiaOk74XsjcvggIDeuczA+x8JYNqNGgHG3GQTDgbd0ES6H+oAaS1pYMrinN5cVk53LpfQYDYWtQA2LZ8iWXsBw+JF9qJ3Z7luCWkC8kAChwGAUAefRQ7kbxOhkHJ8lkWKQCPLlzbRGX2IjvkcEndAAApFANJDtAAakifk1O0AAqcwjQUygg5D4uMK6PoAEptAAUm0dVan9+iqgi2iNwV1PjAQdPakz7PYxpOAc-kxTHQikJdnqgYm76A8W57wTudmeRB5T+9R-HmRJ6WKD8Jgxv5yxSvq8wWuSsNO+zwgHOAAVLzv+e6-7zx0NuBaLeExBKgjNsPI+igx69gnsCLO588KVAItfBoNBb5Vx-k-JAd9ZjiA-l-DBNcF5-2ooA1u28ljbnFuBGaEUkCkGxBCBI2R-RWxkG5eU0tR57FAIfdADgaD5H3LA+B6B9I-1jvHMCycIH8OPjA0+cCp4-wALL+0Yb3dAOxqHYXyvIHwfhfCBAUCxLyDtmGFUmuw9wMRZQXRAAYOA6MspMIYCw7o1jFC2LQH9Rxzjqoci5GINxljUAow3DY8sWZAR+Moh6dkOZgnuOiZ47xWZwSxNGNEjkEsOHiC4VAnhQ8LaAXkRnJRrl3LvyNDAHOAByNyr46khB-kkwqLSiGUENF4-QwDA6CUad4GptRKh0AkPkbWT04DgJKWnBRIAz7oB-pkoc-SlgGDIEKHRdEtGlTgIxKItQ2lon0b4fwxjGF5IKbLbyfDAKCOEYo0RchOnHO0AAXk+doBiTFPAAB8-n31rt02xHyvk-JoMxahEtkCmDMcUtEEA+wICYOeWoDh86y1AI5F2cB6EmI9kYu2xxeKCl0uSZmMZoAFERcNGQAjSq1hAGoiA2ivT501uSMMaIADEJYHDvg9jJMioBmSgAZXHJYYCZDa3FUESV6AqH0sEc7KleQB4dW-IoKG9zGXGxhlsxEMz-QFnRZi8kOL0B0IYVhBZARiXkjUuSmMAZZRyr1egT8HsmD+1KpUElIBuVLD+I0AenIQDCoDWK3VCqQDSpALKmNTKlVyGjY7AorkCzFlLPoO+c9Om7xCp4AA-NoeatxtCoG0LcLeHtF4BvTaql5D9FKFvkNoUtP961lurRaStQLiFkDDRMComwKXDCdnJAtlM94lu0HU66dT+11O5nU21D5BTBiJg7CdGb8xBmGh7DdmAADqTi4lyyfEsJ4RokD1LLBFA5shmnzuOS+n+IU+lBvQKiyVZsr06z8Le+9eyn0voaZEzA77OmfpYksX9ykuTfusvkcWyqbKXshFOltSkwXvO+YxSFHk7w-t7FAEwB8AOxkciBx9pxn0hDqW+jpOHYNDU2HugqWrryUaw4BmjTHQP0fAyC-Q0HWOyD6Y2r8F5FC-i2UhkcpGGIUeoV2O58REi1H8vUegjCMVsCxYBBiUSdl1GGQ5W9clvBnKMUEfT8qmWDN0zAQVbo4VFLuRUPQ2n8oue8yYmQlR9wQuYqgBw2w4D0vNTGS15nOiEvtfvGMTrs42n3Dgc8skYzfurGUWQw6IRuTYJrE9IVOgxglUyk2hrpIkWyw7YrnLnK5c1KVJgd40NFY5XAQs9RAjyyKd+hEuSzjqHHRxptApziSA9tGqrUrbWJoW4qwViI7LrHVSY5y-kzyydqHc4wTQM0OUM0gJU65Tl+AgPYG8FIECZcUPR7QTBtwSxnkU6TmrZM8cSbupte2fzuyTmZwH2qDuyJAEdyoJ2Ey0jVdwNEDFCqm1O8gJU2KrNWrxTa5VHrzP9Tc2Z5m7DIcBfcLUD7a4yYDBpxvNH52NCY8NLi-FDn8csrZSABY+c0BTJobShYOqvP+opwzjHzanKRwMec+z6LHPrPPaMD2PO2B882tM3RM0wd41JyU8nUk4cNtgIgJHUAUcKbkGdiXcWruy8C0mxXzj1syAijEa7n2muni1TqqCVUNxLnmtdA7dANUgCOci39AAVSHgRsgD3QwDn3tl4RAA). I would like to visualize the edge bundles with the **weight** field.

[screen shot showing the dependencies data stream in the data viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXYtM.png)

The main code snippet is below

```
{
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": 
        {
          "name": "path",
          "data":  "dependencies",
          "field": "treepath"
        },
        "data": "dependencies"
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "line",
          "interactive": false,
          "from": {"data": "path"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "interpolate": {"value": "bundle"},
              "strokeWidth": {"field": "weight"}
            },
            "update": {
              "tension": {"signal": "tension"},
              "x": {"field": "x"},
              "y": {"field": "y"}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

This is my first stackoverflow question. Please pardon me if my question is substandard. Please let me know if I need to provide more specific information.

Thank you so much for all your help!

Sincerely,
Nagesh